# Obtain Parent node in nested query when child is known using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

What is the best practice for using a lambda expression to obtain a parent node when the child element is known in a parent/child relationship and the base class is stored in a List?

For example:

```
<Countries>
    <Country name="x">
        <States>
            <State name="y">
                <Counties>
                    <County name="z"/>
                </Counties>
            </State>
        </States>
    </Country>
</Countries>
```

If I know the county name, what is the best practice to obtain the state?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your county node as an XElement in C#, you can do,

```
    XElement state = county.Ancestors().Where(x => x.Name == 
    "State").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: In my case, I have loaded all of the xml into a List<Countries>, based on classes coming from a web service, which then has the sub-elements for state and county. Could you clarify your answer Ryan? I am not finding a definition for Ancestors in a List<>, and when using system.xml.linq it creates more problems. Apologies for not stating that up front.

Comment: @Greg Are you using `XElement` or `XmlElement`?

Comment: I tried using Xelement as suggested. Ideally neither because main element is a class, and each wrapper a list<t> Array of that class. 

If I was drilling down I would do something like:
    var countyid = countries.firstordefault(x=>x.Name == “US).states.firstordefault(y=>y.Name == “Texas”).counties.firstordefault(z=>z.ID == cmbCounty.selectedvalue).ID

But in this case I need to do it in reverse because I have the county but need the stateid to be sent in a transaction to the database.